# Cuda How to run many threads from global function? One kernel which runs many threads

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, cuda

I need to make one part of calculations to be parallel. It is calculations on vector and sometimes I need to do one operation on every values. So I want to make it to be parallel.

I cant explain my calculations on example(its only simple example, not my algorithm):
I am moving a pointer forward and when I found number 5 then Im adding 5 to every numbers in vector.

So I want to avoid doing it on Host and copying all Big vector to Device <=> Host(repetable) after every pointer moving. I suppose that it could be less efficient than do everything on Host.

So I got an idea that I will copy all vector to Device once and then I will start algorithm.

Here is a simple cope presenting my problem:

```
__device__ void devFunction(long long unsigned int *arr, long long unsigned int param, long long unsigned int N) {
    long long unsigned int i = blockIdx.x* blockDim.x+ threadIdx.x;
    // do something ...
}

__global__ void globFunction(long long unsigned int *arr, long long unsigned int N) {

    do {
        devFunction(arr, param, N); // I want to run many threads here like <<<...>>>

        // do something ...

    } while(/* ... */);
}


int main() {
    // declare array, alloc memory, copy memory, etc.
    globFunction<<< 400000, 256>>>(arr, N); // I think here should be <<<1,1>>>
    // do something ...
    return 0;
}
```

So it is possible to do it? Run multiple function parallely from kernel? Any other solutions?

Comment: Why do you need to spawn more threads from a single cuda thread? Can't you just invoke a kernel on many threads from the host and run the computation in parallel?

Comment: It could be slower because every threads will do the same think -> moving pointer through this Big vector forward and comparing it (in example case) with number 5. I need do it only in one thread and only once. Only the other computations on each thread.

Comment: @nosbor: so you would like to know whether it is possible to "do something" in parallel? That isn't a very precise question, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible. But you might be going about this the wrong way: Only the main kernel function should have need to compute the thread index, and you should design the code in such a way that each thread has *independent* work to do. That's the nature of a parallelizable problem. There should be no branching or cross-thread data dependence within the parallel code.

As a crude skeleton example, the code should look something like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(int * indata, int * outdata)
{
  unsigned int tid = threadId.x + blockDim.x * blockId.x; // or suitable analogue

  device_computation(indata + tid, outdata + tid);
}

__device__ void device computation(int * in, int * out)
{
  // This code does not care about the thead ID
  // -- it is already local to one single thread
  *out = *in * 2;
}
```

You really shouldn't have *any* need to know `indata[j]` in order to compute `indata[i]`. If you do, then you have to partition your data such that *all* data that's needed to perform the computation is visible exclusively to a single thread.

If the code cannot be designed that way, it will suffer serious performance hits, and you should investigate whether it is actually worth parallelizing.

(The example is overly simplistic; the opportunity to use block-shared memory should certainly be taken into account. However, this does not affect the fact that each thread should be able to operate independently of the other threads.)

Comment: Yes but when you consider example problem it is not possible to make it looks like this.

Comment: @nosbor: I can't really see what your code is doing, but you should try to partition it into parts that can be done independently, or with minimal synchronisation.